# Disk inside plot in mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, disk

I have a question about using plot and disk together in one manipulate function in mathematica.

I have this piece of code right now:

```
Plot[h[t], {t, 0, ttot}, PlotRange -> {0, 30}]
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  h0 + v0*t - 1/2*g*(t)^2, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 8}, {0, 11.5}}
  ], 
 {t, 0, ttot, 0.001}, {m, 0.001, 0.1, 0.001, ImageSize -> Tiny}, {v0, 
  0, 5, 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny}, {h0, 0, 10, 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny}
 ]
```

What I want to do is display a disk inside the plot representing a flying object (its position is on the curve, according to actual time and height). How do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange network!  You might be interested in asking Mathematica-related questions at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ which is where most of the Mathematica activity happens these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show the definitions of the symbols you use : `h[t]`, `v0`, `ttot` etc.
My understanding of what you are after :

```
trajectory[p0_, v0_, a_, t_] = p0 + v0 t - 1/2 a t^2;

x0 = 3;
v0y = 1;
g = 9.81;
ttot = 3;

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[trajectory[{x0, h0}, {v0x, v0y}, {0, g}, t], {t, 0, ttot}, Epilog -> {Disk[trajectory[{x0, h0}, {v0x, v0y}, {0, g}, tcurrent], 0.5]}, PlotRange -> All], {v0x, 0, 5, 0.01}, {h0, 0, 10, 0.01}, {tcurrent, 0, ttot, 0.01}]
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks, The definitions are as follows:

Comment: g = 9.81;
h0 = 0;
v0 = 5;
m = 10;
h[t_, v0_, h0_] = h0 + v0*t - 1/2*g*(t)^2 (*height*)
v[t_] = v0 - g*t (*velocity*)
ttot = (1/g)*(v0 + ((v0)^2 + 2*g*h0)^0.5)